# SQL get last four year data by comma separated month wise

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that stores, number of fruits sold on each day. Stores number of items sold on particular date.

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
    [code] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [amount] int,
    [date]  [smalldatetime] NOT NULL
);
```

Sample data:

| code | amount | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aple | 10 | 2010-01-01 |
| aple | 32 | 2010-01-01 |
| aple | 20 | 2010-02-01 |
| aple | 30 | 2010-03-01 |
| aple | 40 | 2010-04-01 |
| aple | 10 | 2011-01-01 |
| aple | 20 | 2011-02-01 |
| aple | 30 | 2011-03-01 |
| aple | 40 | 2011-04-01 |
| aple | 10 | 2012-01-01 |
| aple | 20 | 2012-02-01 |
| aple | 30 | 2012-03-01 |
| aple | 40 | 2012-04-01 |
| aple | 10 | 2013-01-01 |
| aple | 22 | 2013-01-01 |
| aple | 20 | 2013-02-01 |
| aple | 30 | 2013-03-01 |
| aple | 40 | 2013-04-01 |

I need to write a query to list out the sum of amounts earned each month for the last 4 years as comma separated list.

Expected result:

| Year | AmountEarnedInMonthWise |
| --- | --- |
| 2010 | 42, 20, 30, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 (Sum of month wise data as comma separated list) |
| 2011 | 10, 20, 30, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 |
| 2012 | 42, 20, 30, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 |
| 2013 | 32, 20, 30, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 |

Comment: @Zhorov I have updated the table with smalldatetime datatype, using SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `SQL Server 2019` ? `SQL Server` does not have `VARCHAR2` & `NUMBER` data type

Comment: Try using string_agg and group by YEAR([DATE]).  DATE is not a great column name choice by the way...

Comment: On versions of SQL that don't support cross tab, you can do something like `select year(date), sum(case when month(date)=1,amount,0), sum(case when month(date)=2,amount,0) ... from table group by year(date)`

Comment: @Squirrel I have updated the datatypes and i have written above data for just representation purpose and actual data is different and now datatypes are correct.

Comment: `int(5)`  for `SQL Server`, Integer does not have size or width.

Comment: @Squirrel any mistake left out to find .? in my question.? please correct my question..

Comment: test data in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=77f06c4f083253263ddad036009a18eb) for everyone if needed

Answer (score 3):

A combination of `PIVOT` and `CONCAT_WS()` is an option:

```
SELECT
   [Year], 
   AmountEarnedInMonthWise = CONCAT_WS(
      ', ', 
      ISNULL([1], 0), 
      ISNULL([2], 0), 
      ISNULL([3], 0), 
      ISNULL([4], 0), 
      ISNULL([5], 0), 
      ISNULL([6], 0), 
      ISNULL([7], 0), 
      ISNULL([8], 0), 
      ISNULL([9], 0), 
      ISNULL([10], 0), 
      ISNULL([11], 0), 
      ISNULL([12], 0)
   )
FROM (
   SELECT YEAR([date]) AS [Year], MONTH([date]) AS [Month], amount
   FROM Data
) t
PIVOT(
   SUM(amount) 
   FOR [Month] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
) p
```

Comment: Hmm, I came up with `STRING_AGG` but that doesn't take into account missing months https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bc01cef1482dfaf3ee78eaa43eab18d7

Comment: @Charlieface, yes, that was my first attempt (but with a small calendar cte to get all the missing months).

Answer (score 1):

similarly approach using PIVOT and cte

```
; with months as 
( select 1 as m
union all
select m+1 as m from months where m<12)
, years as 
(
select min(Year(date)) as y,max(Year(date))  as y1 from data
union all
select y+1 as y,y1  from years where y < y1
), codes as
(
select distinct code as c from data
)
, my as 
(
select y,m,c from months cross join years cross join codes
)
 

select 
y as year, 
c as code, 
concat([1],',',[2],',',[3],',',[4],',',[5],',',[6],',',[7],',',[8],',',[9],',',[10],',',[11],',',[12] )as amount
from 
(
select my.*, isnull(amount,0) as amount 
from data d right join my
on my.m =month(date)
and my.y=year(date)
and my.c=code

) as s
pivot
(
sum(amount) for m in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
)p
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=21accc41c1b108fa6a5c63e410b77498)